# Can I conjugate a complex number: $\sqrt{a+ib}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Can I find the conjugate of the complex number: $\sqrt{a+ib}$?

Actually my maths school teacher says and argues with each and every student that we can't conjugate $\sqrt{a+ib}$ to $\sqrt{a-ib}$ because according to him $\sqrt{a+ib}$ isn't a complex number.

Please give some proofs, or some good explanations along with replies.

Comment: Has your instructor defined the argument (Arg) of a complex number?

Comment: $\sqrt{\dfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}}=\sqrt{e^{2\pi i/3}}=e^{\pi i/3}=\dfrac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is definitely a complex number. (Though it's certainly true that you have to take great care in the order of conjugation v. square roots.)

Comment: Note:  the OP has reposted the question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918349/can-i-conjugate-a-complex-number-sqrtaib

Answer (score 2):

The notation $w=\sqrt z$ is used to denote one of the two solutions to the equation:
$$
w^2 = z.
$$
If $w=\sqrt z$ is one such solution, the other one is $-w=-\sqrt z$.

Now if $w=\sqrt{a+ib}$ you have $w^2 = a+ib$ and $(\bar w)^2 = \overline{w^2} = \overline{a+ib} = a - ib$. So it is true that the conjugate of $w$ is one of the two square roots of $a-ib$: 
$$
\overline{\sqrt{a+ib}} = \pm \sqrt{a-ib}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You first have to define what is meant by "the" square root of $\sqrt{a+ib}$, because there are two candidates. We can see this by writing $a+ib$ in polar form $re^{i\theta}$. Then $r^{1/2} e^{i(\theta / 2)}$ and $-r^{1/2}e^{i(\theta / 2)} = r^{1/2}e^{i(\theta/2 + \pi)}$ both square to the correct value.

One can resolve this ambiguity by choosing, for example, whichever one has the smaller angle as measured from the positive real axis.

In any case, both numbers can be conjugated (as can any complex number), respectively, to $r^{1/2} e^{-i(\theta / 2)}$ and $r^{1/2}e^{-i(\theta/2 + \pi)}$.

Comment: I meant conjugating sqrt(a+ib) not their roots.

Answer (score 0):

If $x+iy=\sqrt{a+ib}$, then I can show that:
$$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{a\pm|a+ib|}{2}}$$
$$y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-a\pm|a+ib|}{2}}$$
NOTE: not all of these will work!

Compare the four values (by changing the $\pm$ into $+$ and $-$) each for $x$ and $y$ to find which square to make $a+ib$, then flip the sign of the imaginary part for the complex conjugate.

*If you'd like me to show how I got those results, just ask!*