# Can I conjugate a complex number : $\sqrt{a+ib}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Can I conjugate a complex number: $\sqrt{a+ib}$  ?

Actually my maths school teacher says and argues with each and every student that we can't conjugate $\sqrt{a+ib}$  to $\sqrt{a-ib}$  because according to him $\sqrt{a+ib}$ isn't a complex number.

Please give some proofs, or some good explanations along with replies.

PS : Sorry for double post, my previous question wasn't understood properly by the reply-ers because of absence of $\sqrt{}$ symbol :(

Comment: Your teacher is not correct. Consider $a=3$ and $b=4$. Then $\sqrt{3+4i}=\sqrt{(2+i)^2}=\pm(2+i)$.

Comment: @AlexSchiff That's an example. How about in a general context?

Comment: Write $a+bi$ as $re^{i\phi}$ with $r \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $\phi \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I was just addressing the part of the post where the teacher said that you can't conjugate $\sqrt{a+ib}$ because $\sqrt{a+ib}$ isn't a complex number. This is false if we take $\sqrt{z}$ to mean the positive branch of $z^{1/2}$.

Comment: You might find http://www.mathpropress.com/stan/bibliography/complexSquareRoot.pdf interesting.

Comment: @AlexSchiff Your reason to say the teacher is not correct when they say that $\sqrt{a+ib}$ is not a complex number, is a bit peculiar since, in your example, $\pm(2+i)$ is **not** a complex number.

Comment: @Did of course, you are correct. The $\pm$ is a typo, and I should have said that we are taking $\sqrt{a+bi}$ to be the positive branch of $z^{1/2}$. This is the usual meaning of $\sqrt{z}$ but I have seen an author mean $\sqrt{z}=z^{1/2}$, the multi-valued map.

Comment: @AlexSchiff I guess you are referring to the cut associated to the argument interval $(-\pi,\pi]$. Then, for $z=-1$, your suggestion is that $\sqrt{z}=i$. Since (you say) $\sqrt{\bar z}=\overline{\sqrt{z}}$, one gets $\sqrt{\bar{z}}=\bar i=-i$. But $\bar{z}=-1$, thus $i=\sqrt{-1}=-i$. Oops... Note that I strictly followed the procedure you said was foolproof. You know what, I think I will side with the OP's teacher on this one... :-)

Comment: @Did, actually I never said that my method worked for all complex numbers, just one in particular. If a statement is not true for one example, it is not true in general.

Comment: @AlexSchiff You lost me. The OP's teacher cast doubt on the identity $\overline{\sqrt{z}}=\sqrt{\bar z}$, I provide an example where the identity is wrong, this seems to prove **quite generally** that the assertion "For every complex number $z$, $\overline{\sqrt{z}}=\sqrt{\bar z}$" is wrong. A counterexample suffices to kill a theorem.

Comment: u can do that, but it depends on ur choice of the branch of the $\sqrt{ }$

Comment: @YonedaLemma No. Please refer to what happened with your (now deleted) answer.

Comment: @Did, the way I interpreted the teacher's statement was that $\sqrt{z}\notin\Bbb C$ for every $z\in\Bbb C$. This is somewhat misleading when we use a branch cut for $\sqrt{z}$.

Comment: @AlexSchiff "√z∉ℂ for every z∈ℂ" ?? This seems an *extremely* uncharitable interpretation. To assume that the teacher is unaware that for some complex numbers $z$ the equation $z=w^2$ has some solutions $w$ is a convenient way to neglect what they say, but maybe not optimal to understand the quite correct and most necessary point they are making.

Comment: @Did, difference of opinion :-). From what OP has told us, the teacher was not careful in his/her explanation. It is possible that OP misinterpreted what his/her teacher wrote (no offense OP), but I was going off of what OP wrote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps what your teacher means is that the notation $\sqrt{a + ib}$ is ambiguous, because there are two square roots of $a+ ib$, and unlike with real numbers there is no good way of distinguishing which square root you are referring to when you write $\sqrt{a + ib}$.  However, you are right when you write $$\overline{\sqrt{a + ib}} = \sqrt{a - ib}$$ if you take it to mean that if $z^2 = a + ib$ then $\bar{z}^2 = a - ib$.  This follows from the fact that $$\overline{zw} = \bar{z} \bar{w}$$ for all $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Hence the correct statement is actually that $\overline{z^2}=(\bar z)^2$, yes?

Comment: @Did Are you referring to the last equation I wrote?  I was generalizing to say that $\overline{zw} = \bar{z}\bar{w}$ for all $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$, but maybe that was unclear since I didn't say what $w$ was.

Comment: Actually I was referring to the fact that your post exposes (competently) a (correct) result about squares and conjugates while the OP asks about square roots and conjugates.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  Thank you.

Comment: The $\sqrt{z}$ is to be a solution of $w^2=z$. First you should choose a branch for $\sqrt{}$ (u ve infinitely many choices for that). Once u chose which brach u want to take for $\sqrt{}$ you come out with $2$ possible values for $\sqrt{z}$ (for a $z\in\Bbb C$ where $\sqrt{z}$ is defined, which depends on the choice of branch).

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental theorem of algebra allows us to state that there are two different square roots for a given complex number; but what's a positive/negative complex number? This is an explanation of Taylor's statement ("there is no good way of distinguishing which square root you are referring to when you write $\sqrt{a+ib}$").

There is a formula for the square root of a complex number (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Algebraic_formula)):
$$\sqrt{a+ib}=\pm\left(\sqrt{\frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{2}}+i\operatorname{sgn}(b) \sqrt{\frac{-a + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{2}}\right)$$
So if $b\mapsto -b$, assuming $b$ to be strictly positive, then
$$\sqrt{a-ib}=\pm\left(\sqrt{\frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{2}}-i\sqrt{\frac{-a + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{2}}\right)$$
Then, indeed, $\sqrt{a-ib}=\overline{\sqrt{a+ib}}$ if $b\neq 0$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: "Then, indeed, $\sqrt{a-ib}=\overline{\sqrt{a+ib}}$." In the sense that two pairs of complex numbers coincide?

Comment: @Did Well, no. What I meant was that if one chooses $\sqrt{a+ib}=\left(\sqrt{\frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{2}}+i\operatorname{sgn}(b) \sqrt{\frac{-a + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{2}}\right)$ and $\sqrt{a-ib}=\left(\sqrt{\frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{2}}-i\sqrt{\frac{-a + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{2}}\right)$ (or alternatively replacing $+$ with $-$), then $\sqrt{a-ib}=\overline{\sqrt{a+ib}}$.

Comment: And the approach fails if $b=0$. You might want to mention this more prominently.

Comment: @Did I had mentioned that $b$ was to be "strictly positive".

Comment: Yes I know, but you did so only in passing, while it is crucial to the method. In the same vein, it would be good practice to add "when $b\ne0$" at the very end of the post, to prevent the reader to believe that your conclusion holds in full generality.

Comment: @Did Done.${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Say $$a+ib=z$$ and

$$\sqrt{z}=
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{|z|}e^{\frac{i\phi}{2}} \\
\sqrt{|z|}e^{\frac{i\phi}{2 + \pi}}
\end{cases}$$

for a chosen branch of $\sqrt{}$ - especially $\sqrt{z}$ should be well defined by the choice of the branch (this is important to mention, because for defining $\sqrt{}$ we have always to cut out a line including $0$ out of the $\Bbb C$ plane, f.i. for choosing $\phi\in (-\pi,\pi)$ it has to be for $z:=a+ib$ that $a>0$ or $b\neq 0$ - for other choices of the range of $\phi$ there apply corresponding restrictions to what $z$ can be).

Thereby we have these two values for the conjugate of the root
$$\overline{\sqrt{z}}=
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{|z|}e^{\frac{-i\phi}{2}} \\
\sqrt{|z|}e^{\frac{-i\phi}{2 + \pi}}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: $\;\sqrt{1+i}=\pm\sqrt[4]2\,e^{\frac{\pi}8i}\;$ , so which one of these two square roots I have to take to evaluate the conjugate?

Comment: You seem to believe that $\sqrt{z}$ is a unique complex number. Or not?

Comment: Sorry but the edited version is not crystal clear either. Could you be more explicit?

Comment: What are these, complex numbers equal to two different complex numbers simultaneously?

Comment: Thus, for example, $\sqrt{-1}=\{i,-i\}$? Why not, but then (i) this convention should be mentioned prominently in the answer since this goes against  common practice and (ii) I fail to see why, earlier on, you mention "a chosen branch of √". There is nothing to choose if $\sqrt{z}$ is a pair of complex numbers. (Note that the formulation "The square root is defined as **a** solution of so and so" is, strictly speaking, absurd when there are several solutions, and the preceding is a try to give it some meaning.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider

$$\sqrt{a+ib}=\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\log(a+ib)\right)=\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\log\left|a+ib\right|+i\theta_n\right),$$ where $\theta_n=\phi+\pi n$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $\phi= \text{Arg}(a+ib)/2$.

We then have
$$\sqrt{a+ib} = \sqrt{\left|a+ib\right|}\left(\cos\theta_n+i\sin\theta_n\right).$$
This expands to get
$$\sqrt{\left|a+ib\right|}\left(\cos(\phi+\pi n)+i\sin(\phi+\pi n)\right),$$ and then
$$\sqrt{\left|a+ib\right|}\left((-1)^n\cos(\phi)+i(-1)^n\sin(\phi)\right).$$

Hence, we have the complex **numbers**
$$\sqrt{a+ib} = \pm\sqrt{\left|a+ib\right|}\left(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi\right).$$ So the symbol $\sqrt{a+ib}$ produces two complex numbers, not just the one, which is why your teacher might say $\sqrt{a+ib}$ is not a complex number.

Comment: This seems to define $\sqrt{a+ib}$ as **a pair** of complex numbers, right?

Comment: This seems hardly related to the question (or I am missing something).